PostGIS: Custom projection matrix from known points
I have a PNG image of a map (mercator) and known points in a table like this:



coord_map - geometry(Point, 0)
coord_real - geometry(Point, 4326)




010100000000000000000000000000000000000000 (0,0)
0101000020731300006ECA357336752E40686E759D8AC44740 (15.228931045833829,47.53548019632291)


01010000000000000000409F400000000000408F40 (2000,1000)
010100002073130000E239642C84742E408848BB31BBC44740 (15.227570903048164,47.53696271557516)



( pixel 0;0 is 15.2289,47.5354 in reality and pixel 2000;1000 is 15.2275,47.53696 )
How do I generate an projection matrix for this image (and any other image with enough known points, I think two known points should be enough?) and get the real coordinates (in 4326) of an unknown pixel on the map (e.g. ST_MakePoint(1000,500)).
I think affine transformation is the professional word for what I am searching for, but how do I apply this via PostGIS functions?
I need to determine the scaling factor of the map as well as the translation in the x and y axis. I can assume the maps are not rotated (up=north)

PostGIS is probably the wrong tool, you'd be better off using a GIS like QGIS to georeference the image before importing it in to PostGIS

Thanks for the suggestion Ian, but I need to do it in the DB because I have many images, not only a single one and new images/known points might be added later on. This question is a simplified and broken down example

Two points are certainly not enough for transformation of a Mercator -- Distance from the Equator increases to infinity at the poles. At 47N, the progression is quite pronounced.
